# Why do I get NPE when trying to get response in ServletUnit?

Tags: java, jsp

Here is my ServletUnit code:

```
File webXml = new File(path/to/web.xml);
ServletRunner sr = new ServletRunner(webXml);
ServletUnitClient sc = sr.newClient();
PostMethodWebRequest request = new PostMethodWebRequest("http://localhost/responseHtmlView.jsp");
sc.getResponse(request);
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.responseHtmlView_jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.responseHtmlView_jsp</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.responseHtmlView_jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/responseHtmlView.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

responseHtmlView.jsp

```
<html>
  <head><title>First JSP</title></head>
  <body>
    <p>Test text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I precompile jsp using Tomcat 7 and Ant (jasper2 task) and during code execution I get exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
  at org.apache.jsp.responseHtmlView_jsp._jspInit(responseHtmlView_jsp.java:32) 
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49) at com.meterware.servletunit.WebApplication$ServletConfiguration.getServlet(WebApplication.java:587) 
  at com.meterware.servletunit.WebApplication$ServletRequestImpl.getServlet(WebApplication.java:775) 
  at com.meterware.servletunit.InvocationContextImpl$ExecutionContext.getServlet(InvocationContextImpl.java:248) 
  at com.meterware.servletunit.InvocationContextImpl.getServlet(InvocationContextImpl.java:86) 
  at com.meterware.servletunit.InvocationContextImpl.service(InvocationContextImpl.java:76) 
  at com.meterware.servletunit.ServletUnitClient.newResponse(ServletUnitClient.java:126) 
  at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.createResponse(WebClient.java:647) at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResource(WebWindow.java:220) 
  at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:181) 
  at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158) 
  at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.getResponse(WebClient.java:122) 
  ...
```

Which is this line:

```
_el_expressionfactory = _jspxFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletConfig().getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
```

With _jspxFactory being initialized by:

```
   private static final javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory _jspxFactory =
      javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getDefaultFactory(); // == null
```

This is a bug, as reported here: 
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40820

but I can't find a way around it as there's not much information about what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get jsp servlet response, to get HTML body from it and then be able to compare it to another one for differences check. This action is a functionality test so I don't want to run a full server and I don't want to engage anything as heavy as Selenium.